# Cumulative sum after 64 in R(Conditional Cumulative sum)

Tags: r, conditional-statements, cumulative-sum

I am new to R. I am not sure how to do the following function in R. I am able to do this in excel. But not able to do it in R. Can anybody help me in this?

I want to get the cumulative sum of the counter value once it reaches 64,

The following is my data,

```
x
57
57
57
57
57
57
58
58
58
58
61
61
62
62
1
1
11
16
16
16
16
16
16
22
22
22
27
28
```

I want the cumulative sum after the count reaches 64. I am not sure how to do that in R.

The following is the output I require,

```
x
57
57
57
57
57
57
58
58
58
58
61
61
62
62
65
65
76
81
81
81
81
81
81
87
87
87
92
93
```

Can anybody help with doing this?

```
                                                                                          Thanks
```

Comment: @jeremycg here the data doesn't hit 64. But its a long loop and generally it reaches 64. If not also, can we write a logic when the difference between the previous value is negative?

Comment: you might want to put some representative data, and it's not clear how the transform you describe goes from the input->output in your example

Comment: @jeremycg Exactly.. possibly 3-4 ? It may increment in future.

Comment: @jeremycg It is based on timestamp. Here 64 value was not recorded at the timestamp. But it is going past 64 only. So we can add with 64.

Comment: @jeremycg Thanks a lot... it is working. But I am not understanding the logic behind it. In the first line, we find the difference. From the given data, I get one negative data, rest all positive...

But the diffs[diffs < 0] <- 64 + diffs[diffs < 0] line should add only when less than 0 right? How is it adding all the values after it? 

I am getting the output I want. But just didn't understand the concept yet. If you don't mind, can you explain it?

Comment: @akrun I have changed it now. Thanks

Comment: I think you still have an error - the values at 76 and above need to have -1 taken from them

Comment: Another version would be `indx <- cumsum(c(0,diff(df$x)<0))==1;
 df$x[indx] <- 64+df$x[indx]`

Comment: @akrun This is the same logic I employed in excel. Just didn't know how to translate it to R. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data is resetting at 64, and continuing on, and you want it to keep the 64, try:

```
diffs <- c(dat$x[1], diff(dat$x)) 
diffs[diffs < 0] <- 64 + diffs[diffs < 0]
cumsum(diffs)
```

An explanation:

The first line takes all the differences from one number to the next, starting with the initial value (in the example case, 57).

The second line finds all negative diff values, and changes them to 64 + what they were - if it was 62 changing to 2, we need to add on 4: 2 to hit 64 and then 2 more.

The third line takes the cumsum to give the final values.

Comment: This code is not working properly when it increaments second time. An additional 64 is added in the second increment. Is there a way we can change it?

Comment: yes.. after the second reset the values should start from 129, but here it is starting from 198(another 64 is added)

Comment: Yeah this is the right one, I just now found and also crossed checked with yours..Thanks!!

Comment: I have another doubt.. If the value is 0, I want to assign the previous value of the column.. Is there a way to write the logic?